# FileSystemObject - Not able to open files saved into folder

Tags: excel, vba

Below is the code which is intended to open files and paste the required data into those files and close those files after completing its work. While I am running this code, none of the file in opening and

> *Run-time error-13 : Type mismatch*

is throwing at this line of code

```
Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1))
```

Please suggest where the bug is. Although it is working fine into some other file:

```
Sub split()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
    Dim fl As File
    Dim fldr As Folder
    Dim akb As Workbook
    Dim tkb As Workbook
    Dim RawAL As Worksheet
    Dim RawAL1 As Worksheet
    Dim RawSR As Worksheet
    Dim RawSR1 As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Integer
    Dim ALSummary As Worksheet
    Dim ALSummary1 As Worksheet

    MsgBox "Please select the path where Access Log Report are being saved."
    Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).Show

    Set fldr=fso.GetFolder(Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1))
    lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

    For Each fl In fldr.Files
        Workbooks.Open fl

        Set akb = ActiveWorkbook
        Set tkb = ThisWorkbook
        Dim i As Integer

        Set RawAL = akb.Sheets("Raw Access Log")
        Set RawAL1 = tkb.Sheets("Raw Access Log")
        Set RawSR = akb.Sheets("Raw Submittal Report")
        Set RawSR1 = tkb.Sheets("Raw Submittal Report")
        Set ALSummary = akb.Sheets("Access Log Summary")
        Set ALSummary1 = tkb.Sheets("Access Log Summary")

        RawAL.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        RawAL.AutoFilterMode = False
        RawAL.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        RawAL1.Activate
        RawAL1.AutoFilterMode = False
        RawAL1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=ALSummary1.Range("b5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        RawAL1.Range("A1:f65000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        RawAL.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        RawSR.Visible = xlSheetVisible
        RawSR.AutoFilterMode = False
        RawSR.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        RawSR1.Activate
        RawSR1.AutoFilterMode = False
        RawSR1.Range("a1").CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=1, _
                Criteria1:=ALSummary1.Range("b5"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
        RawSR1.Range("A1:E500").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        RawSR.Range("a1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

        RawSR.Visible = xlSheetHidden
        ALSummary.Activate
        akb.Close True

    Next fl
End Sub
```

Comment: Without digging too deeply into this, I would use `Set akb = Workbooks.Open(fl)` instead of opening your workbook then using `Set akb = ActiveWorkbook`

Comment: Can you manually open files in the problem folder?

Comment: When you get the code working you should post it on  [Core Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).  There a few things that could be cleaned up not relates to the folder issue.

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs    Actually "Error 13" is throwing at this line of code : "Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker).SelectedItems(1))" only. Rest code seems fine to me.

Comment: That is information that really should be a part of the actual question. Could you please [edit] that in?

Comment: @K.Dᴀᴠɪs Thanks, just edited the question again.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `.GetFolder()` method after using `.show`, grabbing the value from `.show` to ensure that a folder was indeed selected *(which would return `-1`)*, and the proceed using the string from `.selectitems()` to pass the folder path.

Something like this should work:

```
with application.filedialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    if .show = -1 then 
        set fldr = fso.getfolder(.selecteditems(1))
    else
        msgbox "No Folder selected"
    end if
end with
```

Comment: @k.Davis , I tried to using the above code suggested by you, but it's still giving that error - "Run-time error'13' : Type mismatch"

Comment: @K.davis I can't see any difference between the two...please suggest.

Comment: I had a typo on the variable name `fldr`, which you could see if you checked the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/53660640/revisions). But can you be more specific on which line is throwing the error please?

Comment: set fldr = fso.getfolder(.selecteditems(1))
This is the line...where this error comes.

Comment: This code works just fine for me. I can see that you copied the line from this webpage instead of from your code as Excel would have automatically capitalized certain methods for you. Can you please copy the line directly from your VBE so I can ensure you had no typos?

Comment: Well these are the top few lines of code here :
Sub split()

Dim fso As New FileSystemObject
Dim fl As File
Dim fldr As Folder
Dim akb As Workbook
Dim tkb As Workbook

MsgBox "Please select the path where Access Log Report are being saved."

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    If .Show = -1 Then
        Set fldr = fso.GetFolder(.SelectedItems(1))
    Else
        MsgBox "No Folder selected"
    End If
End With

Comment: @PremPrakash yeah I've tried your code, and it works just fine. I am not entirely sure why it's not working for you, as you can only select a folder since you're using `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`. The only reason that I could see it throwing a 13 error is that you are trying to set something other than a folder to `fldr`, but I am not sure how that's possible with using `msoFileDialogFolderPicker`. You are 100% sure it's that line throwing the error?